# Clarity on Classify's ClassPriors option

Tags: machine-learning

I'm looking for clarity on Classify's `ClassPriors` option, and I've listed some specific questions below. According to the documentation:

> ClassPriors is an option for Classify and related functions that
>   specifies explicit prior probabilities to assume for output classes,
>   independent of anything deduced from the training set.

The canonical example/usecase here is for imbalanced data:

```
data = {1 -> True, 2 -> True, 3 -> True, 4 -> True, 5 -> False, 6 -> True};
c = Classify[data, Method -> "LogisticRegression"]
{c[5, "Probabilities"],
 c[5, "Probabilities", ClassPriors -> <|False -> 0.5, True -> 0.5|>]}
(* this yields *)
 {<|False -> 0.452497, True -> 0.547503|>, 
 <|False -> 0.712596, True -> 0.287404|>} (* ok, this makes sense! *)
```

This option is supported in many symbols: `Classify`, `ClassifierMeasurements`, `ClassifierFunction`, etc. So here are some specific questions:

1. If I use it in `Classify`, do I still need to use it in calling `ClassifierMeasurements`? Does one use it in the same way during inference?  What is the interplay between usages?
2. What exactly does `ClassPriors` change mathematically during model training for different `Method` options? For example, it seems to have no consistent effect, so what are the guidelines if any?

   ```
   c = Classify[data, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"]
   {c[5, "Probabilities", ClassPriors -> <|False -> 0.5, True -> 0.5|>], 
    c[5, "Probabilities"]}
   {<|False -> 0.999551, True -> 0.000448898|>, 
    <|False -> 0.998655, True -> 0.00134548|>}
   ```
3. Is the *following usage correct*: I have 1000 negative samples and 6000 positive samples in a binary classification problem, assuming the true distribution has 90% negative and 10% positive?

   ```
   Classify[trainingset, ClassPriors-><|"Positive"->0.1, "Negative"->0.9|>]
   ```

   or

   ```
   Classify[trainingset, ClassPriors-><|"Positive"->6/7, "Negative"->1/7|>]
   ```
4. For multi-class classification, what if I know some of the priors but not all? For multi-label classification, how/can I specify know priors for specific (sub)-labels? Is this even supported?

Any additional examples showing how the `ClassPriors` can help with unbalanced data (if it can) would be very useful.

Comment: As described this seems much more like a statistical methods question rather than a *Mathematica* question.  Have you tried https://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?  I'll note that having "unbalanced data" is not a sin nor is it an impediment to performing an analysis.  Setting priors depends on your objective.

Comment: @JimB no need to worry, this is a Mathematica question, I simply need clarity on the functionalities of a specific option

Comment: At least to me your question still reads as needing statistical help.  Class priors don't "help" with unbalanced data.  You are fitting a particular model and priors don't need to match to the sample size.  Hence, I think you need statistical help rather than *Mathematica* help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is written as if the OP does not know the "purpose" of supplying priors as opposed to "how" to supply priors in *Mathematica*.  Priors do not "help" nor do they "mess with the confusion matrix" (as stated by the OP).  This question should be asked at CrossValidated.

Comment: @JimB please don't, I am only looking for more information/use cases of a particular option

Comment: @JimB I've edited the question to make it clearer and more on-topic, is there anything IYO I should change or add?